# How do I post a link to the feed of a page via the Facebook Graph API *as* the page?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a plugin for a Wordpress blog that posts a link to every article published to a Facebook Page associated with the blog.

I'm using the Graph API and I have authenticated myself, for the time being, via OAuth.

I can successfully post a message to the page using curl via a POST request to `https://graph.facebook.com/mypageid/feed` with e.g. message = "This is a test" and it published the message.

The problem is that the message is "from" my user account. I'm an admin on this test page, and when I go to Facebook and post an update from the web, the link comes "from" my page. That's how I'd like this to be set up, because it looks silly if all the shared links are coming from a user account.

Is there a way to authenticate myself as a page? Or is there an alternate way to POST to a page feed that doesn't end up being interpreted as a comment from a user?

Thanks for any thoughts or suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To post **as** the Page, you need to get an access token for the page by getting an access token for an admin of the Page with the "manage_pages" and "publish_stream" permissions. Then, using that access token, hit https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=THE_ACCESS_TOKEN. You'll get a JSON output of all the Pages that user admins and in there you'll see an access token for each Page. If you use one of those access tokens to POST your message, you will be doing so **as** the Page. The process is outlined in the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#page-login) (sorry, it's kind of buried).

Comment: When I originally posted this question, the problem was simply a bug in the API that has since been addressed. This is the correct answer to the question for anyone stumbling upon it now, so I've marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, [it's a bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10005).

Comment: A bug in Facebook's API?? GET OUT OF TOWN.

Comment: I find your lack of faith in Facebook's API disturbing!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use enable_profile_selector 
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the comments by "Nam Thai" on this thread: http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/graphapi/graph_27.html. This solved the problem for me.